# Find new x and y on a scaled raphael svg image using css3 matrix transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am trying to create a jquery plugin that enables zooming and navigation like google map. In this plugin user's can select an area of an image like [SummerHtmlMapCreator](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/demos/s/u/summerstyle/365ccfd644f2b008c33f0046d2ba1a8f/summer-html-image-ma_1355318513_demo_package/index.html). I have created an svg of the image with the help of rapheal.js because it's easy. I create paths on mouse slick and close a path on double click. My problem is that when i zoom the image, i am not getting the x,y properly. i have implemented zooming via css3 transform matrix. I have wrapped the svg in a div and i apply the transform matrix on the parent div. i have googled a lot and tried a lot of options.  Currently i calculate new x and y as follows :

```
newX = mouseX * scaleMatrixWidthValue;
newY = mouseY * scaleMatrixHeightValue;
```

i am really stuck here and any help would be greatly appreciated. What am i doing wrong here?
Jsfiddle can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/34dJa/1/

Comment: Have you got the code on a jsfiddle or something, so people can have a play ?

Comment: yes i will create a jsfiddle

Comment: the Jsfiddle link is [link]http://jsfiddle.net/34dJa/2/